# Error occurred during installing Aptana 3 Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, aptana

- My pc system is Windows Xp .
- Today i want to install Aptana
- Eclipse plugin （the Eclipse version is Eclipse Juno 4.2）

I do it step by step like this：

- Open Eclipse
- Help -> Install New Software
- Add (on the top right)
- Enter the following link for Aptana Plugin with Eclipse Juno:  http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install

  - Click OK
  - Put a check mark for Aptana Studio 3
  - Next -> Next -> Finish

Plugin is installing and then this window appears：
[image: Exception]

I don't how to solve it.

Comment: please write the error of it !

Comment: The steps mentioned above is working for me

Answer (score 0):

The URL seems to be downloadable (for me).

This might just be a transient error with the Aptana server, or it might conceivably be a networking error in your network, ISP, or national network.

Try it again.

Comment: wow! it finally works untill i try for three times. thank u very much.